# HSQLDB error on primary key definition

Tags: sql, syntax-error, primary-key, hsqldb

I have the following SQL I am running in my local HSQLDB 2.3.2 database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countries (
    country_id              PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL,
    country_version         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    country_name            NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    country_label           NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    country_description     NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
    country_code            NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT uc_countries UNIQUE (country_id, country_version, country_label, country_description, country_code)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS states (
    state_id                PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL,
    state_version           INTEGER NOT NULL
    state_name              NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    state_label             NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    state_description       NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    country_id              INT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries(country_id),
    CONSTRAINT uc_states UNIQUE (state_id, state_version, state_label, state_description, country_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS addresses (
    address_id              PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL,
    address_version         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    address_line_1          NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    address_line_2          NVARCHAR(500),
    address_line_3          NVARCHAR(500),
    address_city            NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    state_id                INTEGER NOT NULL,
    address_postal_code     INTEGER NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES states(state_id),
    CONSTRAINT uc_addresses UNIQUE (address_line_1, address_city, state_id)
);
```

The goal of my `PRIMARY KEY`s are to have them be auto-incrementing (start: 1, step by: 1) integers that can't be NULL.

When I execute this, I get:

```
Error: unexpected token: PRIMARY: line: 2
SQLState:  42581
ErrorCode: -5581
```

What is going on here? Anything else look bad about my table/constraint setup?

Comment: I don't know the details of defining tables in HSQL, but in other databases you need a type.  Something like:  `country_id int not null primary key . . . `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a data type for the column, plus the `primary key` keyword goes to the end ([as documented in the manual](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#N10FE9))

```
country_id  INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

you are also missing a comma after the column definition in `countries.country_description` and `states.state_version`